# cascading dropdown in wp8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I'm try to create cascading dropdown when i select first one it's working fine.On SelectionChanged i'm try to bind second drop down on code behind it's show the result fine.But Dropdown show empty.here is my code..

```
 Location ld = new Location();
            ld = categoryList.SelectedItem as Location;
            string id = "0";
            try
            {
                id = Convert.ToString(ld.id);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            { }
            if (id != "0")
            {
              //  lstSublocation.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                var lst = _lstlocation.Where(z => z.id == id).Select(z => z.sub_location).ToList();
                lstSublocation.ItemsSource = lst;
            }
```

In lst show 2 items.

```
<toolkit:ListPicker x:Name="lstSublocation" Foreground="Black"   
                         BorderThickness="2" SelectionMode="Single"  
                        VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="12,0,10,460" BorderBrush="LightGray"  Height="68" >
                    <toolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}" Margin="12 0 0 0" Foreground="Black"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </toolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>
                    <toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0 21 0 20">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}"
                                       Foreground="Black"
                                       />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
                </toolkit:ListPicker>
```

Here is front end code  .....  :( 2 hours struggle with this code like wrestlemania fight... :)

Comment: `SelectedItem="{Binding name}"` looks odd. What should this do? You already bind to name in item templates.

Comment: I remove this..Try different ways to get data :)

Answer (score 0):

Code should work (as posted), this is probably where the problem is

```
var lst = _lstlocation.Where(z => z.id == id).Select(z => z.sub_location).ToList();
lstSublocation.ItemsSource = lst;
```

Put a break point at `lstSublocation.ItemsSource = lst;` and check what `lst` is

Make sure it's actually a `List<your_model>` and that `your_model` has a Property of `name` not just a public variable.. like this

```
public class sample_model
{
    public sample_model()
    {
        this.name = "default";
    }

    public string name { get; set; }   // this is bindable
    // public string name;             // this is NOT bindable
}
```

Comment: @RichardRay Yeah, can we get a screen shot of debug out of that list please?.  It should look like a tree, not just a list of values.